# Simulating a jump

Tags: java, android, math, velocity

I am looking to simulate a jump for my Android game, however I have no clue how to achieve this properly. I have been looking up velocity a bit, but I just can't translate it to code myself. Looking for some demo code to get this worked.

The current height variable is called: *centerY*, this has *427* as default value. When you jump, it has to go to about *360* then go back to *427*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: `s = 1/2 * a * t^2`. That's what you should start with.

Comment: read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Comment: I have tried some stuff that just didn't make any sense at all. I just don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: If you understand what a quadratic function is, you're set. If you don't, you should study up on the math.

Comment: @alex: great link! +1

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things I'll assume jumping instantly accelerates the player. Here's some very basic pseudocode of how things should work. Note that you'll need to figure out a better way to handle ground collisions than a simple height check.

```
G := 9.8 or something other appropriate constant
defaultY := 427;

player {
    var centerY
    var velocityY

    update(dt) {
        if (centerY < defaultY)
            velocityY += G * dt
            centerY += velocityY
        else
            velocityY := 0
            centerY := defaultY
    }

    jump() {
        dh := 427 - 360
        velocityY := -sqrt(2 * G * dh)
    }
}
```

In this scheme you'll call `player.update` on every frame, giving it the time elapsed from the last frame. Note that the velocity is calculated from the second of the kinematic equations:

[image]

Which you should definitely know about.

Answer (score 0):

427 - 360 = 67
so, your object need to jump by 67 points.

but, you need gravity and verticalspeed variables of course
so, you've to tell what is the value of your gravity variable

Comment: I'd love to give you those variables, can you tell me how I get them? I'm really new to JAVA and this stuff, but dying to learn it.

Comment: you can't get them, you have to set them first...
thats not fast food...